# getting checkboxfor value checked by default in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a model which has a field

```
[DisplayName("Receive occasional email notifications about new services or features")]
public bool ReceiveEmail { get; set; }
```

In my view I want  a checkbox which will come checked by default.

I tried this:

```
<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.registerModel.ReceiveEmail, new { @checked = "checked" })%>
```

But did not work...

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Arnab

Comment: Why you do not just set the value in your model before passing it to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to set your view model property in the controller action rendering this view:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        registerModel = new registerModel
        {
            ReceiveEmail = true
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Now all you need in your strongly typed view is:

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.registerModel.ReceiveEmail) %>
```

and the checkbox will be automatically *checked*.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure this is the "proper way", but it certainly worked. @checked = "checked" certainly does not! Thanks.